# 3D models with texture using Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying texture images with 3D models with Three.js. 
I picked up demo from https://threejs.org/examples/?q=cars#webgl_materials_cars.

What I am trying to do is, Over the car I want change body color to some image. If try solid colors it works, but for textures it's not redering correctly

What I tried so far,

```
* Some base code for SCENE is not included

    initCar();

    function initCar() {
        var dracoLoader = new THREE.DRACOLoader();
        dracoLoader.setDecoderPath( '/js/draco/gltf/' );

        var loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader()
        loader.setDRACOLoader( dracoLoader );
        loader.load(
            // resource URL
            './../models/ferrari/ferrari.glb',
            // called when the resource is loaded
            function ( gltf ) {
                let model = gltf.scene.children[0];

                // CHANGE MATERIAL
                let part = model.getObjectByName( 'body' )

                // THIS WORKS
                // part.material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial( {
                //     color: 0xff4400, metalness: 1.0, roughness: 0.2, name: 'orange'
                // } )

                // THIS DOESN"T
                var textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
                textureLoader.crossOrigin = true;
                textureLoader.load('/images/2.jpeg', function(texture) {
                    console.log("TEXTURE LOADED", texture)
                    texture.anisotropy = 16
                    var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { map: texture, opacity:1, transparent: true} );
                    part.material = material
                });

                model.scale.set(20.5,20.5,20.5)
                scene.add( model );
                renderer.render( scene, camera );

            },
            undefined,
            function ( error ) {
                console.error( error );

            } 
        );
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please verify if it works with this texture: https://threejs.org/examples/textures/crate.gif ? Besides, try it without setting `transparent` and `opacity`.

Comment: @Mugen87 If I try any Image over geometry created using code(like box or sphere) it works fine. How ever for same image on models it doesn't.

Comment: Is there any restriction for 3D Models?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conclusion is :

Problem is within model I am using, code works fine but to allow texture to applied on models, Models require UV texturing.